# Output an Image for Each Word Rather than the Whole String in PHP Using Pango and Cairo

Tags: php, cairo, pango

I am working on a solution to automatically make an image of each word of a large document that contains a complex script (Khmer in UTF-8).  I've found Pango and Cairo which can render Khmer correctly.  I'm not much of a programmer, so I started with the PHP versions of Pango and Cairo.  But I am not sure how to break up a string and produce an image for each word automatically.  There are no "real" spaces between words, just the Unicode character U+0200B (a zero-width space).

Would someone be willing to help me?

Here's the code I am currently using that outputs the whole string:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
/* Make a 300x300px image surface */
$s = new CairoImageSurface(CairoFormat::ARGB32, 300, 300);
$c = new CairoContext($s);

/* Set the background to white */
$c->setSourceRGB(1, 1, 1);
$c->paint();

/* Let's draw using black 'ink' */
$c->setSourceRGB(0, 0, 0);

/* Make a Pango layout, set the font, then set the layout size */
$l = new PangoLayout($c);
$desc = new PangoFontDescription("KhmerOS Regular 28");
$l->setFontDescription($desc);
$l->setWidth(250 * PANGO_SCALE);

/* Here is the text */
$l->setMarkup("កាល​ដើម​ដំបូង​ឡើយ ព្រះ​បាន​បង្កើត​ផ្ទៃ​មេឃ និង​ផែនដី។");

/* Draw the layout on the surface */
$l->showLayout($c);

/* Output the PNG to the browser */
$s->writeToPng("php://output");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out using foreach:

```
<?php
//header("Content-Type: image/png");
$str = "កាល​ដើម​ដំបូង​ឡើយ ព្រះ​បាន​បង្កើត​ផ្ទៃ​មេឃ និង​ផែនដី។";
//$words = explode('​', $str);
$words = preg_split('/ |​/', $str);

$i=1;
foreach($words as $word) {
/* Make a 300x300px image surface */
$s = new CairoImageSurface(CairoFormat::ARGB32, 300, 300);
$c = new CairoContext($s);

/* Set the background to white */
$c->setSourceRGB(1, 1, 1);
$c->paint();

/* Let's draw using black 'ink' */
$c->setSourceRGB(0, 0, 0);

/* Make a Pango layout, set the font, then set the layout size */
$l = new PangoLayout($c);
$desc = new PangoFontDescription("KhmerOS Regular 28");
$l->setFontDescription($desc);
$l->setWidth(250 * PANGO_SCALE);


/* Here, we use Pango markup to make part of the text bold */



$i++;

$l->setMarkup($word);

/* Draw the layout on the surface */
$l->showLayout($c);

/* Output the PNG to the browser */
//$s->writeToPng("php://output");
$s->writeToPng(dirname(__FILE__) . '/test'.$i.'.png');
echo $img = "<img src=\"test".$i.".png\">";
echo $i;
}
?>
```